# mysql rollup with count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux

I am stuck with mysql ROLLUP on count column. Can you please guide me.

I wrote following mysql query

**The query:**

```
 SELECT (SELECT store.StoreName from store 
          WHERE store.storeOwnerId=redeem.StoreNo)
             AS CompanyName,
        (SELECT mscheme.SchemeName from mscheme 
          WHERE mscheme.SchemeNo = redeem.SchemeNo)
             AS SchemeName,
 count(*) AS Count  
 FROM kirana_app.redeem GROUP BY redeem.SchemeNo 
 ORDER BY CompanyName;
```

** Output **

```
 CompanyName,SchemeName, Count
'Dwarkesh', 'September-saffola', '25'
'Dwarkesh', 'September-Tea', '20'
'Nitin stores', 'Testing Scheme', '1'
'Nitin stores', 'September-Parle', '63'
```

I need to roll up with Count column Like

Output like :

```
 CompanyName,SchemeName, Count
'Dwarkesh', 'September-saffola', '25'
'Dwarkesh', 'September-Tea', '20'
 **Dwarkesh', NULL, '45'**
'Nitin stores', 'Testing Scheme', '1'
'Nitin stores', 'September-Parle', '63'
 **'Nitin stores', NULL, '64**'
```

Comment: Have you tried "GROUP BY CompanyName"?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to do proper joins instead of subqueries.

```
SELECT s.StoreName AS CompanyName,
m.SchemeName AS SchemeName,
COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM redeem r
INNER JOIN store s ON r.StoreNo = s.storeOwnerId
INNER JOIN mscheme m ON m.SchemeNo = r.SchemeNo
GROUP BY s.CompanyName, m.SchemeNo 
WITH ROLLUP;
```

The `ORDER BY` is implicitly done by `GROUP BY`.